# How to blur caret in CKEditor?

Tags: focus, ckeditor, blur

I am using CKEditor in inline mode. I am focusing and immediately blurring (for testing) using the following:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.dom.element.get( e.currentTarget.getDOMNode());

editor.getEditor().focus();
editor.getEditor().focusManager.blur(true);
```

I want to blur the editor and `focusManger.blur(true)` results in the toolbar being hidden. However, the caret is still focused. For some reason, I cannot find a way to defocus and remove the caret. I have tried calling `focus()` on another DOM element, but the caret still persists.

How can I call `blur()` to remove the caret as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I was able to solve this is to blur the `contenteditable` div:

```
CKEDITOR.currentInstance.element.$; //Grab the DOM node which is the contenteditable
CKEDITOR.currentInstance.element.$.blur(); //Blur it
CKEDITOR.currentInstance.focusManager.blur(true); //CKEditor's blur hides the toolbar
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this enough?

```
editor.editable().$.blur();
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another more shorter way that works for me:

```
editor.window.$.frameElement.blur();
```